# Is it possible to return a search result page from Google in PHP?

Tags: google-api

I need to be able to return a page of results from Google programmatically. Does anyone know if this is possible? Thank you.

Comment: In case anyone else wants to know the answer to this, it's called Google Custom Search and the full API is available from Google here: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/

Comment: FYI: The PHP code Google supply is in beta.